# How do I start gvim with a maximized window?

Tags: linux, configuration, vim

I would like to start gvim, from the command line, into a maximized window - how can I do this?

I have no wish to always start in a maximized window (that is, **not** configure it as default in .vimrc), but rather choose to provide a parameter to the program.

That is, running `gvim <parameter(s)>` should start the program in a maximized window but just running `gvim` should start the program with the default size.

Comment: Possible same on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/140419/how-to-start-gvim-maximized

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just like many other Gtk+ apps, gvim understands the parameter `-geometry`. Try for example

```
gvim -geometry 500x500
```

Answer (score 16):

For me (I'm on Ubuntu 11.10), adding this to my .vimrc seems to do the trick.  No need for geometry settings, etc.

```
if has("gui_running")
  " GUI is running or is about to start.
  " Maximize gvim window.
  set lines=999 columns=999
endif
```

Comment: works nice in gvim (Ubuntu 12.10). No need for vimrc, the one can change gvim.desktop and add in TryExec param --cmd "set lines=100 columns=200" . That way you can configure gvim shortcuts individually. Higher values made gvim appear on other desktop.

Comment: Actually, if you change font size, u need to change lines/cols again if you dont want to appear on other desktop

Comment: this cause warnings on my ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to change the size by going into the vimrc file, where you can specify the size or maximize it on open.

Have a look here.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size

Comment: From the question: "(that is, not configure it as default in .vimrc)", from the answer "change the size by going into the vimrc file".  Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows 7 I have this in my _vimrc:

```
" Run maximized in diff mode
if &diff 
   au GUIEnter * simalt ~x
else
   set lines=55 columns=130
endif
```

So when I run Vim in diff mode (e.g. from TortoiseSVN), Vim starts maximized.

Similarly, it can be changed to:

```
" Run maximized in GUI
if has("gui_running")
   au GUIEnter * simalt ~x
endif
```

Answer (score 5):

Put to `.vimrc`

```
" Maximize GVim on start
if has("gui_running")
  set lines=999 columns=999
endif
```

stolen from:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size

Comment: Isn't this the same as Ryan's answer (and wikia link on grep's)?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you can try add following to your `_vimrc`

```
au GUIEnter * simalt ~x
```

Note that `~x` comes from keyboard shortcut for menu option, it might vary on different OS language. So check the shortcut for desire option and try it.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux I use this in my .vimrc:

```
augroup maximizewindow 
    autocmd! 
    autocmd VimEnter * call system('wmctrl -i -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz -r '.v:windowid)
augroup END
```

This auto command will trigger after the VimEnter event has been triggered. When that happens it runs wmctrl on the current window to maximize it.

This requires that you have [wmctrl](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl/) installed.

Comment: works like a charm, had some error with my previous config  `set lines=999 columns=999` with bigger resolution:

`(gvim:25777): Gdk-WARNING **: 20:57:09.043: Native Windows wider or taller than 32767 pixels are not supported`

Now solved with: `autocmd VimEnter * call system('wmctrl -i -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz -r '.v:windowid)`