# How to maximize vim's windows on startup with .vimrc?

Tags: vim

Can I add something to my .vimrc or .gvimrc to make gvim always start up in a maximized GUI window?

Comment: Could you add some specifics to the question instead of restating the title? Are you talking about maximizing GUI windows with GUI vim?

Comment: Yes! Can I do it directly from .vimrc?

Comment: Related: [linux - How do I start gvim with a maximized window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722684/how-do-i-start-gvim-with-a-maximized-window)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On linux with most window managers and `wmctrl` installed you can maximize Gvim using the following command:

```
call system('wmctrl -i -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz -r '.v:windowid)
```

. Note: I am intentionally avoiding `-b add,fullscreen` mentioned in `man wmctrl` as it means different thing: at least in fluxbox that means that from now on this desktop you can see only either gvim or something else at a time, not both, and gvim is left without window decorations (not that I really care about them). E.g. if you popup yakuake* gvim disappears until yakuake hides.

* terminal emulator, pops like console in some FPS games

Comment: @amorenoc Yup, I was already reading mailing list when this change came (or I did not know about this variable at all). It was introduced in vim-7.3.031.

Comment: This only worked when starting gvim from the command line, not from the launcher, however, this always worked: `autocmd GUIEnter * call system('wmctrl -i -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz -r '.v:windowid)`

Answer (score 12):

It looks like if you're using Windows, it's as easy as adding this line into your .vimrc:

```
au GUIEnter * simalt ~x
```

(type `:help maximize` or `:help win16-maximized` for details)

Apparently there's no standard way to do it on other platforms from your vimrc. The simplest trick without knowing which platform is to add

```
set lines=999 columns=999
```

to your .gvimrc. There are a few other tricks that can help at the Vim Wiki's [Maximize or set initial window size](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size) page.

Comment: The autocommand works. However, on Windows 10 v1909 I experience that sometimes after startup the gvim window is not yet ready to receive input and so it fails. For me it works if I introduce a little delay right before the autocommand: `sleep 100m`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial size of the Vim Window by adding the following line to `~/.vimrc` :

`set lines=50 columns=100`(just an example)

I set my vim to my screen resolution, i.e. `set lines=768 columns=1366`. Now my Vim editor automatically launches in fullscreen.

Comment: Check the vim wikia page for more info : [click here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size)

Comment: This solution has a lot of drawbacks. First off, it is not environment independent. In some systems it also does not work well, for instance, in my ubuntu settings, this approach leads to blank result after reopening file in the same terminal.